# List all columns in a SQL Server database that are null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that by table will list all columns in a database that contain no value. Is there a better way to do it other than a) get a list of nullable columns in the DB and b) check if each of the columns have any data

Comment: No, that's the way to do it.

Comment: Why would you need this? I'm thinking maybe someone could give you an alternative. At first glance, this request looks strange.

Comment: I have two DB - same schema used by two versions of the application. I am trying to find what are the differences in data storage - what columns that earlier did not have any value is now being used. I have Red Gate tools but it looks like my needs fall somewhere in between schema compare and data compare